# Spring Entity Attribute Cant be found in REST

Tags: spring, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

Example of my entity and it has an interface that extends CrudRepository.
if i Post -

ex.

```
id=1,
name="sample",
code="smpl",
campus_id=1
```

in Web *what should be the correct parameter name of this*

it says campus_id should not be null;; w

```
    import javax.persistence.AttributeOverride;
    import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
    import javax.persistence.Column;
    import javax.persistence.Embedded;
    import javax.persistence.EmbeddedId;
    import javax.persistence.Entity;
    import javax.persistence.Id;
    import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
    import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
    import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
    import javax.persistence.OneToOne;
    import javax.persistence.Table;
    import javax.persistence.Transient;

@Entity(name="depts")
@Table(name="depts")
public class Department {
    @Id
    int id;

    String name;

    String code;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "campus_id")
    Campus campus;


    public Campus getCampus() {
        return campus;
    }

    public void setCampus(Campus campus) {
        this.campus = campus;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }



    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }




    public String getCode() {
        return code;
    }

    public void setCode(String code) {
        this.code = code;
    }



}
```

when making post in CrudRepository interface.. it says missing column "Campus_ID" what should i do to mapped it to the id of the campus class?

Comment: "depts" should have a foreign key column 'Campus_ID' mapped from table 'Campus'

Comment: i cant add *int campus_id* because it gets an error.. its already mapped in the class campus. im wondering what should be the name of the campus_id foreign key in ORM mapping of hibernate. like Campus_id

Comment: how have you mapped your Campus, can you update that here

Comment: Is this a Spring Data Rest question  (i.e. is your repository exposed as a RepositoryRestResource) or do you have a Spring MVC controller handling the post? If the latter post your Controller.

Comment: error messages should be paste here.